# How to unpack data from array of bytes?

Tags: python, c#, struct

I have a data respresented in array of bytes.
Need to unpack the data to python array:

in C# its looks (start=4):

```
    static T BytesToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes, int start)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        if (bytes.Length < size)
            throw new Exception("Invalid parameter");

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, start, ptr, size);
            return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
```

I tried to do the same in python. But it not works correctly

```
    import struct
    decode_buf = [251,0,160,64,217,53,223,189,98,22,36,191,214,90,91,63,0,144,238,178,0,176,31,180,0,16,70,51,106,43,30,187,96,88,149,58,74,186,9,58,16,204,136,60,0,167,2,189,187,214,28,65,221,101,123,63,98,208,59,62,216,163,181,188,230,152,30,189,76,19,180,20]
    parsed_data = struct.unpack_from("<H", bytes(decode_buf))
```

correct output must be:

```
data{
acc: [0] = 0.01669887
acc: [1] = -0.03189754
acc: [2] = 9.802424
gyo: [0] = -0.002413476
gyo: [1] = 0.001139414
gyo: [2] = 0.0005253894
pos_glob_odometry: [0] = -0.1089894
pos_glob_odometry: [1] = -0.6409665
pos_glob_odometry: [2] = 0.8568548
rot: [0] = 0.9820231
rot: [1] = 0.1834121
rot: [2] = -0.02217285
rot: [3] = -0.03872003
vel: [0] = -2.777233E-08
vel: [1] = -1.487206E-07
vel: [2] = 4.611502E-08
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed something with struct, you have to specify the number of Hexadecimal you have in your bytearray:

```
parsed_data = struct.unpack_from("<%de" % int(len(bytes(decode_buf)) / 2),bytes(decode_buf))
```

Note1: divided by two because 'e' means floating value on two bytes so you should have len//2 16bits items.

Note2: make sure decode_buf is mod 2 (eventually add padding)

Comment: Looks like its not working.  i've edited the question (put correct decode_buf). With your opinion output is:
''(251, 16544, 13785, 48607, 5730, 48932, 23254, 16219, 36864, 45806, 45056, 46111, 4096, 13126, 11114, 47902, 22624, 14997, 47690, 14857, 52240, 15496, 42752, 48386, 54971, 16668, 26077, 16251, 53346, 15931, 41944, 48309, 39142, 48414, 4940, 5300)'

But its not what i needed(